# mod_rewrite redirect to folder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've read many posts on this subject, but for some reason none of code seems to work.
If I have a domain `example.com`, I would like to redirect it to `example.com/folder` without the user knowing about the redirection.

```
# file: public_html/.htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /folder/$1 [L]
```

But it doesn't send me to `folder`. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove leading slash and include a negative lookahead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+folder/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]

RewriteRule ^((?!folder/).*)$ /folder/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: It almost works perfectly, but if I would do this `example.com/folder/index.php`. This works as well.

Comment: `example.com/index` redirects to `example.com/folder/index` which is great. But if I go to `example.com/folder/index` it goes to `example.com/folder/index` as well instead of `example.com/folder/folder/index` and generate a 404.

Comment: So you mean it should goto `example.com/folder/folder/index` I would think `example.com/folder/index` should not be rewritten as that already starts with `/folder/`

Comment: but I don't want users to be able to figure out where they are redirected to. Is this possible?

Comment: So I guess when users enter `example.com/folder/index` you want to show `example.com/index` in the browser while internally loading `example.com/folder/index` is that right?

Comment: I just want to add `/folder/` to the path (without the user seeing it). If the user enters `example.com/folder/index`, they will be redirected to `example.com/folder/folder/index` and get a 404.

Comment: I've been learning about regex the past day, but I can't figure out why (?!folder/) is essential. Without it I get HTTP 500 response. Could you please explain why?

Comment: `(?!folder/)` is negative lookahead which means match this pattern only if URI is not starting with `/folder/`.

Comment: but how can ^(.*)$ generate an error? Even if `folder/` is not part of the URI

Comment: Because rewrite engine runs again and again until any condition is matching.